# Specifying data type of columns in a values subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

Is there a way to specify the data types of the columns in a `values` subquery? Something like `(values (...)) as tmp_name (colname::type)`?

#### Contrived Example

Say I have a table with a `uuid` column:

```
/* setup */
create table foo (id uuid);
insert into foo values 
    ('aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff00001111'),
    ('aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff00002222'),
    ('aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff00003333');
```

If I try to `join` against it using a `values` subquery, postgres assumes the column is type `text` and throws a **type error** (even though the same strings worked for direct insertion into the `uuid` column) :

```
select foo.id from foo 
inner join (values 
    ('aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff00001111'),
    ('aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff00000000'))
as tmp (id) on foo.id = tmp.id;

ERROR:  operator does not exist: uuid = text
LINE 5:     as tmp (id) on foo.id = tmp.id;
                                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

**Explicitly casting each value:**

It works if I add the explicit cast to the values themselves, but it would be nice not to have to cast every single value and just specify the datatype of the column as a whole:

```
select foo.id from foo 
inner join (values
    ('aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff00001111'::uuid),
    ('aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff00000000'::uuid))
as tmp (id) on foo.id = tmp.id;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast once on the join predicate:

```
select foo.id from foo 
inner join (values 
    ('aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff00001111'),
    ('aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff00000000'))
as tmp (id) on foo.id = tmp.id::uuid;
```